# Forcing Mathematica to Output $1/\sqrt2$ as $\sqrt2/2$

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

I am trying to force Mathematica to output $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$ as $\frac{\sqrt2}{2}$.

I tried:

```
{1, Sqrt[2]}*Sqrt[2]
```

Which outputs:

```
(* {Sqrt[2], 2} *)
```

Now,

```
Divide @@ {Sqrt[2], 2}
```

returns:

```
(* 1/Sqrt[2] *)
```

So I tried:

```
HoldForm[Divide @@ {Sqrt[2], 2}]
```

But that didn't work. Any suggestions to get my preferred output for this particular example?

Comment: you may want some `{1, Sqrt[2]}*Sqrt[2] /. {x_, y_} :> Divide[HoldForm[x], y]`

Comment: may be `Divide @@ HoldForm /@ {Sqrt[2], 2}`

Comment: Is it reasonable to ask *why* you prefer $\sqrt{2}/2$ to $1/\sqrt{2}$? While they have the same leaf counts, the latter is simpler in that it uses 1 rather than 2. (Too many secondary school teachers incubate a fear of radicals in denominators, insisting that the student rationalize the denominators.)

Comment: There's a closely related question: [Mathematica Sec and Csc](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7799/245). The title makes it seem not to be a duplicate, but the methods in two of the answers are applicable here.

Comment: I'd like to thank all my colleagues for a wonderful collection of answers.

Comment: Murray, I don't think I recognize the phrase "leaf counts." Can you explain that to me?

Comment: I should perhaps mention that your approach, and your accepted answer, are in no way making *Mathematica* represent `1/Sqrt[2]` as `Sqrt[2]/2` in output. Rather the question seems to be about printing `Sqrt[2]/2`. It may be worth updating the title and text accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A slight variation of garej's comment:

```
Divide @@@ HoldForm[{Sqrt[2], 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: this looks like the same, more or less, as @garej comment

Answer (score 6):

If you really insist on getting exactly this output within a standard evaluation, you can do the following:

```
Unprotect[Power];
Format[Power[2, Rational[-1, 2]]] := HoldForm[Sqrt[2]/2];
Protect[Power];
```

This leads to the desired output:

```
1/Sqrt[2]
```

> $$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$

```
Sin[1/Sqrt[2]]
```

> $$\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)$$

```
N[%]
```

> 0.649637

I would only do this if you're sure this is the one and only form in which you wish to display this number.

Answer (score 6):

So long as it is only for output purposes, there is probably no real harm in doing this, and so it does not seem to be a matter of "force" in this case--defining an output form is a perfectly reasonable thing to do. The situation here is rather like in [this recent question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103633/chopping-matrix-elements-real-or-imaginary), and so I propose a similar solution.

The most sensible (and least intrusive) way to accomplish it, in my opinion, would be the following:

```
MakeBoxes[1/Sqrt[2] | Power[2, Rational[-1, 2]], form_] :=
 MakeBoxes[Sqrt[2]/2, form];
```

Please let me know if this fails to cover any use cases.

Answer (score 4):

I would make my own `SomethingForm` function like this:

```
SpecialForm[expr_] := expr /. {
   1/Sqrt[2] -> HoldForm[Sqrt[2]/2]
   }

SpecialForm[1/Sqrt[2]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
SpecialForm[5 10 + 3^Sqrt[3] + 1/Sqrt[2]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]