# Adjusting Mark McClure's ComplexTicks function in Stan Wagon's book

Tags: plotting

I'm starting to read chapter 11 of Stan Wagon's third edition of Mathematica in Action, a section written by Mark McClure (and there is a package for the notebook).

I start with:

```
f[z_] := z^2;
Subscript[z, 0] = 0.9 + 0.15 I;
orbit = NestList[f, Subscript[z, 0], 10]
```

Then:

```
Attributes[ComplexTicks] = Listable;
ComplexTicks[s_?NumericQ] := {s, s I} /. 
  Thread[{-1. I, 0. I, 1. I} -> {-I, 0, I}]
```

What this does, I believe, is create a list of tick marks drawn with the specified labels. For example:

```
ComplexTicks[Range[0, .4, 0.1]]
```

Produces:

{{0., 0}, {0.1, 0. + 0.1 I}, {0.2, 0. + 0.2 I}, {0.3, 
  0. + 0.3 I}, {0.4, 0. + 0.4 I}}

So, for example, at 0.0 we'll mark with 0; at 0.1 we'll mark with 0.+0.1I; etc. Now, his next code is:

```
ListPlot[{Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ orbit, Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {Automatic, ComplexTicks[Range[0, 0.4, 0.1]], None, 
   None}]
```

Which is supposed to produce this image:

[image]

But that was in an older version of Mathematica. In Mathematica 11.1.1, it produces this image.

[image]

The current way to set FrameTicks in Mathematica is FrameTicks->{{left, right},{bottom, top}}. So I adjusted the code as follows:

```
ListPlot[{Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ orbit, Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {{ComplexTicks[Range[0, 0.4, 0.1]], None}, {Automatic, 
    None}}]
```

But that gives this image:

[image]

Any way to turn off the real zeros in each complex tick number?

**Update:** Thanks to the help from my colleagues, I gave this a try.

```
Attributes[ComplexTicks] = Listable;

ComplexTicks[s_?NumericQ] := {s, s "\[ImaginaryI]"} /. 
  Thread[{-1. "\[ImaginaryI]", 0. "\[ImaginaryI]", 
     1. "\[ImaginaryI]"} -> {-I, 0, I}]

f[z_] := z^2;
z0 = 0.9 + 0.15 I;
orbit = NestList[f, z0, 10];

ListPlot[{Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ orbit, Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {{ComplexTicks[Range[0, 0.4, 0.1]], None}, {Automatic, 
    None}}]
```

The resulting image is next:

[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: Related: [Chopping matrix elements, real or imaginary](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/103633/27951).

Answer (score 4):

At some point, Mathematica started showing the real part in inexact complex numbers. To workaround this, I would change `ComplexTicks` to something like:

```
ComplexTicks[s_?NumericQ] := {s, s Defer[I]}
```

or

```
ComplexTicks[s_?NumericQ] := {s, s HoldForm[I]}
```

Comment: Or: `ComplexTicks[s_?NumericQ] := {s, s "\[ImaginaryI]"}`.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a visualization requirement, perhaps you could use:

```
ComplexTicks[s_?NumericQ] := {s, ToString[s] <> ToString[" \[ImaginaryI]"]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: That would produce some pretty horrifying output for `ComplexTicks[10^-1]` or `ComplexTicks[.000001]`.

Comment: @CarlWoll Yep, you're right, it would.